# New DELL R330 - No support for Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation, dell, dell-perc

I just bought a new Dell R330 with and H330 RAID controller. When I try to install Server 2008 R2, the installation program cant find my Raid setup. The Raid is up & running and if I try Server 2016, it finds the discs and I can install the OS. So there is no problem with the RAID setup.

I have tried tons of drivers, but it looks like Dell removed support for Server 2008 R2 the 6th of December 2016. Thats what they are stating with the OS deploy drivers for this machine.

Any suggestion what or where to find drivers for Server 2008 R2 and for my new Dell R330? Or is it mission impossible?

I need to install a systembackup from my old server, thats why I desperately need to install this old OS before I upgrade it.

Best regards, Joakim

Comment: Sounds like a discussion you should have with your Dell support and sales staff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally i found the correct driver.

So if someone is looking for it, it should be:

SAS-RAID_Driver_98GDG_WN32_6.603.06.00_A03

Regards, Joakim